# Lookbehind behavior

Tags: regex, search, java-8, lookbehind

Why **doesn't** the following lookbehind

```
(?<=to my\s)(checking|savings|CD) | (?<=to\s)(checking|savings|CD)
```

return any matches on:

```
Can you transfer from my CD 200 dollars to my checking, please?
```

despite properly returning a match (`checking`) on:

```
Can you transfer from my CD 200 dollars to checking, please?
```

The following however works in both cases:

```
(?<=from my\s)(checking|savings|CD) | (?<=from\s)(checking|savings|CD)

Can you transfer from my CD 200 dollars to checking, please? --> CD

Can you transfer from CD 200 dollars to checking, please?  --> CD
```

I am trying to formulate a regular expression which is able to parse out the destination [which follows 'to'] on the above plus on the following text strings (or similar) as well:

```
- Transfer $20 from checking to savings please.
- Can you transfer from my CD 200 dollars to my checking, please?
- Please send from savings to checking 45.
```

Comment: You appear to have a space before the pipe in the look behind regex. The sentence has a comma there

Comment: If you want Java to ignore spaces in your regex, you need to turn on the [`COMMENTS` flag](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#COMMENTS)

Comment: @MadPhysicist: yes, why don't those spaces affect the execution of the `from` lookbehind though?  Thanks.

Comment: Because the sentences have a space in that case. I'm not sure what's tripping you up here. Work through the match by hand, keeping in mind that any spaces will be matched literally.

Comment: Because it matches `from my CD` which is followed by space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could do it without a lookbehind and make "my " optional `(?:my )?`:

[`to (?:my )?(checking|savings|CD)`](https://regex101.com/r/bpJTID/1)

"checking" or "savings" or "CD" will be in captured group 1.